# Infiniti parking sound volume

Tags: infiniti, warning-sound

I have a 2016 Infiniti Q70L with the proximity alert beeping sound, which is very loud. In the owner's manual it is mentioned as sonar but nothing regarding volume control.

How can I turn the volume down?

Comment: What year is your Q70L? What does the owner's manual say about that system?

Comment: @CharlieRB It's a 2016 and I wasn't able to find anything regarding the volume control.

Comment: I didn't find anything in the Owners Manual either. There is a "Volume & Beeps" choice in "Settings". Does that contain anything related to warnings and alerts?